# Testing a sorting function

Tags: testing

we have a function which can sort an non-empty integer array in increasing order. e.g. input: -9 4 5 -1 10 output -9 -1 4 5 10
The question is how can we writes test cases to cover all cases.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Here's my current working: test a: 1 test b: 2 -1 test c: 13 3 2 4 4 4 test d: 2 0 3 -1 7

Answer (score 0):

Using python:

```
>>> from random import randint as rint
>>> test_array = [rint(-100, 100) for i in range(100)] #random array to test
[78, -54, -88, ...]
>>> sorted(test_array) == my_array_after_testing #test if the arrays match up
```

Comment: Thanks. However, my question is assuming we have a sort function writing by our own and we wanna test that sort function. What test should we write to cover all cases?